# Chrome Devtool do not show Content-Encoding in response headers

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, pagespeed, mod-deflate

I´m enabling gzip compression to increase the speed in Google PageSpeed Insights:

If compressed mantaspersonalizadas.com/fonts/Cocktail-Shaker.svg, would save 144.1 KB (65% reduction).
If compressed mantaspersonalizadas.com/fonts/Cocktail-Shaker.ttf, would save 62.6 KB (49% reduction).
If compressed mantaspersonalizadas.com/fonts/Cocktail-Shaker.woff, would save 2.6 KB (5% reduction).

I use an Apache Server, I add this code to .htacess:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype

# For Olders Browsers Which Can't Handle Compression
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
```

**How to check if deflate is enabled in my local server?**

Chrome DevTools don´t show Content-Enconding:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Let's put it to the test.

**Chrome request to example.com (contains gzip):**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
If-None-Match: "359670651"
If-Modified-Since: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT
```

**Chrome response from example.com (does not contain gzip):**

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Date: Thu, 08 Dec 2016 14:06:04 GMT
Etag: "359670651"
Expires: Thu, 15 Dec 2016 14:06:04 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT
Server: ECS (iad/182A)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: HIT
```

**Curl request (clone of Chrome request, contains gzip):**

```
curl -I
    -H "GET / HTTP/1.1"
    -H "Host: www.example.com"
    -H "Connection: keep-alive"
    -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0"
    -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1"
    -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36"
    -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
    -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch"
    -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8"
    -H "If-None-Match: "359670651""
    -H "If-Modified-Since: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT"
    example.com
```

**Curl response (contains gzip):**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 08 Dec 2016 14:18:34 GMT
Etag: "359670651"
Expires: Thu, 15 Dec 2016 14:18:34 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT
Server: ECS (iad/182A)
X-Cache: HIT
x-ec-custom-error: 1
Content-Length: 606
```

**Conclusion**

Chrome does currently not show the content-encoding. Neither does Firefox. I don't know why.

Now that I know they're not showing me everything, I'm never trusting either with response header information ever again.

Curl all the way.

Comment: I stumbled upon this after messing with my production server for 2hrs! I can confirm that, as of october 2017, Chrome+Firefox don't even display the compression hreader for the **main page** in DevTools, but they does for every other resource (such as CSS, JS and even Ajax-loaded page). See here: https://s1.postimg.org/2rv29kk73j/z_Shot_1507239352.png The proposed curl trick works reliably for me.

Answer (score 2):

It seems a problem Chrome browser, I had same problem I though that deflate is not working at the server, but then I tried Firefox and used firebug which correctly showed Content-Encoding in the headers.

Also the downloaded file size in Chrome didnt showed the uncompressed file size, while Firefox showed the correct compressed files size.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jay [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41041738/9517871)

> Chrome does currently not show the content-encoding. Neither does Firefox. I don't know why.

As of december 2018, same behavior in both Chrome and Firefox, and Firebug is gone.

The [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) does the trick for me, showing the correct content encoding within the response headers section ([F12] -> Network Tab -> select a ressource -> Headers Tab).

[Screenshot: content encoding shows up in Firefox Developer Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok9Dd.png)